# Opencv stereo cameras capture and framerate limits

Tags: linux, opencv, v4l2

I am trying to get pairs of images out of a Minoru stereo webcam, currently through opencv on linux.
It works fine when I force a low resolution:

```
left = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
left.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320)
left.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240)
right = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
right.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320)
right.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240)

while True:
    _, left_img = left.read()
    _, right_img = right.read()
    ...
```

However, I'm using the images for creating depth maps, and a bigger resolution would be good. But if I try leaving the default, or forcing resolution to 640x480, I'm hitting errors:

> libv4l2: error turning on stream: No space left on device

I have read about USB bandwith limitations but:

- this happens on the first iteration (first read() from right)
- I don't need anywhere near 60 or even 30 FPS, but couldn't manage to reduce "requested FPS" via VideoCapture parameters (if this makes sense)
- adding sleeps don't seem to help, even between the left/right reads
- strangely if I do much processing (in the while loop), I start noticing "lag": things happening in the real world get shown much later on the images read. This would suggest that actually there is a buffer somewhere that can and does accumulate several images (a lot)

I tried a workaround of creating and releasing a separate VideoCapture for each image read, but this is a bit too slow overall (< 1FPS), and more importantly, image are too much out of sync for working on stereo matching.

I'm trying to understand why this fails, in order to find solutions. It looks like v4l is allocating a single global too-small buffer, used by the 2 capture objects somehow.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found this answer - https://superuser.com/questions/431759/using-multiple-usb-webcams-in-linux

Since both the minoru cameras show the format as 'YUYV', this is likely a USB bandwidth issue. I lowered the frames per second to 20 (didn't work at 24) and I can see both the 640x480 images.